# How to add custom component in context menu of datagrid

Tags: apache-flex

How to add custom component in context menu of datagrid.Here custom component like one text box with formatting details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put components into the context menu.  You can only have menuitems that dispatch a menuclick event.  Unfortunately the context menu in the flashplayer is lacking a lot of functionality like that.

You might be able to highjack the context menu all together and display some sort of title window on a right click, but I am not sure if this is possible or how you would go about trying to achieve it.